# Error in google auth

Tags: openid, google-authentication

I am using google auth. It gives me following error, when login with google, on click learn more
url open, https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID
I follow all steps of this url but error is remain same what should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to activate your API [image: Google API]

Plus create a credential,add your url there 
[image]